# How to deal with Sage Ransomware 2.2 infection?

Tags: malware, antimalware, ransomware

My PC got stuck like this:

[image: Screenshot of desktop with ransome note.]

It's a Sage 2.2 Ransomware. How do I fix this? Does restoring the system help me?

Comment: First piece of advice - don't open any links and don't give them any money. If you have a system restore or backup it's certainly worth trying it, though you may have already been compromised at that point.  You are the victim of a crime, and you should report it.

Comment: Try this link...https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/10732-sage-ransomware

Comment: @user633551 actually, it's Sage 2.2, so maybe this article is a better fit: https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/10865-sage-2-0-ransomware

Comment: @iainpb FWIW, sometimes you _do_ have to give them money if you want your data back. It is regrettable, but properly implemented ransomware will only permit recovery after you pay the ransom.